# How to make click event on an element even the element has cursor event none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to show a warning modal to the user to state that the button is not clickable. The button I used is not clickable due to `pointer-events: none` on class `disable`.

Even if the button is not clickable I want to show a warning if the user clicks on that button.

How I can get the click action and show a warning? Can anyone help?

```css
.disable {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn disable">Button</button>
```

Comment: Looks like an obviously impossible task

Comment: Did this not feel weird while writing?

Comment: Lol @Lain - thinking the same thing

Comment: I mean look at the accepted answer you guys, there was a way around it. It is not literally on the element but from a UX perspective it is effectively on the same element. So no, it is not impossible, and no, it is not weird. The accepted answer helped me a lot. Removing the pointer-events: none from all the elements I needed to do this to would have been a monumental task that would have broken a lot of functionality. So, thank you asker for asking your dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a wrapper and bind the click event on it.

```js
document.querySelector('div').onclick = alert.bind(null, 'hey')
```

```css
.disable {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<div><button type="button" class="btn disable">Button</button></div>
```

Comment: Ah, good idea...

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes well, still rather *pointless* (silly pun).

Comment: Bit Oldschool indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously use a different way than pointer events

```js
const but = document.getElementById("but")
but.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.textContent = "Nope!"
})
but.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.textContent = "Button"
})
```

```css
.disable {
  background-color: light-grey;
  opacity:.5
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="but" class="btn disable">Button</button>
```

jQuery

```js
$("#but")
  .on("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.textContent = "Nope!"
  })
  .on("mouseup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.textContent = "Button"
  })
```

```css
.disable {
  background-color: light-grey;
  opacity: .5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="but" class="btn disable">Button</button>
```